# Continuously running service in Google Cloud Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, microservices

I am trying to figure out how to run a service(1) when it does not receive any calls.

I want to use Microservices Architecture.

Basically i want to run this service (1) when the other service(2) is  receiving calls and all data.

As the service(1) i mentioned is not receiving it would not have to spawn new instances and i would want only the service(2) to scale.

I have noticed [scheduling jobs with cron yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) but the number of calls is limited. 
I need to get this service(1) to be active every 1 min when service(2) is active.

Comment: Please have a look at : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer without knowing more about what service (1) has to do when it is 'active'. It sounds you want cron to launch a task every minute.

You can use cron in conjunction with push queues: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/taskqueue/push/

When creating a push queue task, you can set the property `delay` before adding it to the queue: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/taskqueue/reference#Task

(For me in Python they called it `countdown` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue#google.appengine.api.taskqueue.taskqueue.add)

You could have a cron job that fires every 24 hrs. That cron job would load up your push queue with tasks who's delays are staggered. The delay of the first one is 1 min, the delay of the second one is 2 min, etc.